# Regular Expression Match Filenames

Tags: sql, regex, vbscript

I have a smaller SSIS packat that I am trying to match a file name with VB Regex and delete "said" file. My regex looks like this, `^RegZStmntAdj.[A-z0-9_].\.txt$`, and I am trying to figure out why it won't match any of the files in the directory. This is valid syntax if I am thinking correctly.

```
RegZStmntAdj2_07272011.txt
RegZStmntAdj1_07272011.txt
RegZStmntAdj2_07272011.txxt
New Text Document.txt
```

If I run the regex with `^RegZStmntAdj.*.\.txt$`, it matches the correct files and deletes them. I know * works, but I would like to learn to make more precise Regular Expressions.

```
RegZStmntAdj2_07272011.txt
RegZStmntAdj1_07272011.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Regex:

```
^RegZStmntAdj.[\w_]{9}\.txt$
```

I've used `\w`, which is the same as `A-Za-z0-9`, and told it to match 9 characters so that it will match the `_<date>` part of your filename. You were only matching the first character from there (i.e. the underscore).

Using Powershell to verify:

```
PS> $test = "^RegZStmntAdj.[\w_]{9}\.txt$"
PS> "RegZStmntAdj2_07272011.txt" -match $test
    True
PS> "RegZStmntAdj1_07272011.txt" -match $test
    True
PS> "RegZStmntAdj2_07272011.txxt" -match $test
    False  # (Correct as contains 2 "xx"s in extension)
PS> "New Text Document.txt" -match $test
    False  # (Correct as nowhere near a match!!)
```

To make your regex even more precise, you could use `^RegZStmntAdj\d_[\d]{8}\.txt$`, which translates to:

> A string starting with "RegZStmntAdj", then a digit, then an
>   underscore, then 8 digits, then ending in ".txt"

which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`"^RegZStmntAdj.[A-z0-9_].\.txt$"` matches

- literal RegZStmntAdj at BOS
- **one** character (except \n)
- **one** character of the A-z, 0-9, and _ set
- **one** character (except \n)
- a dot
- literal txt at EOS

but your typical infix "2_07272011" surely has more than 3 characters. Try
`"^RegZStmntAdj[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.txt$"` instead.